# Inconsistency between Firefox and Chrome when removing tags with regex

Tags: javascript, regex

The following regex should replace all tags within the div. However, in Chrome string returns '123' as expected while it returns '"> 123' in Firefox.

```
<html>
<body>
<div><img src="" alt="Test &gt;"> 123</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var string = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].innerHTML;
    string = String(string).replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/,"");
    console.log('String: ' + string);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xvdYb/

I know it's the "greater than" entity that makes Firefox behave differently but why do they produce different results to begin with?

Comment: WTH are you using regex for that? Also your fiddle doesn't contain valid code to reproduce it.

Comment: [`document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].textContent`](http://jsfiddle.net/xvdYb/1/)

Comment: Thanks. The fiddle reproduces the error for me. Using Chrome 31.0.1650.63 and Firefox 25.0.1 (both on Mac).

Comment: [Apparently it does?](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/13438749#13438749) Well I give up :-)

Comment: I was talking about my fiddle. You posted a modified one in the chat. Thanks for the solution but the question still remains why FF and Chrome behave differently in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

You should **never use regex** for this kind of task. Instead use JavaScript DOM functionality:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].textContent.trim()
```

Comment: Thanks but I'm wondering why this specific code behaves differently in FF and Chrome in the first place. The code I'm using in production contains a lot more regex but this is what is essentially causing the problem.

Comment: @user2906759 :: Okay - reason is simple - FF replaces `&gt;` with `>` before it processes your code, so then your replacement makes incorrect html code! :: See this fiddle under FF: http://jsfiddle.net/t3VW9/